# Elusive Hibernate Second Level Cache

Tags: java, hibernate

I am very confused with the output of the following code that tries to avoid Hibernate caching.

I open a fresh Hibernate session, run a query, and check the result when it stops at the indicated breakpoint.  Before continuing execution, I go to MySQL and delete or add a row.  When I continue executing, the query still shows old data and old row count, inspite of the `evictAllRegions()` call on the hibernate cache, while the plain JDBC query shows the updated count (as expected).

Setting *hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache* and  *hibernate.cache.use_query_cache* to false didn't help.  I guess it shouldn't matter as the cache is being cleared manually.

So, why is Hibernate not hitting the database?

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb...");

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    // Old data keeps being returned
    list = session.createCriteria(Language.class).list();

    // JDBC fetches expected count
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from language");
    int x = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) x++; // count the rows

[Breakpoint here]
    session.close();
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictAllRegions();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your transaction isolation?

Comment: If that matters, shouldn't it affect the JDBC call too? It is REPEATABLE-READ on the MySQL server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result of having the transaction isolation level set to REAPEATABLE-READ in MySQL.

When you issue the query from your code, MySQL creates a snapshot of the language table that it continues to present for the remainder of that transaction. So the data is effective cached at MySQL rather than at Hibernate.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read